# How to get a size N Real to Complex FFT from a size N/2 Complex to Complex FFT

Tags: fft

I read someplace that this should be possible, but I can't find any examples of how it is accomplished. Here is my attempt but it doesn't give correct results.

```
function realFFT(real) {
    const n = real.length;
    const halfN = n / 2;

    const complexReal = new Array(halfN);
    const complexImag = new Array(halfN);

    for (let i = 0; i < halfN; i++) {
        complexReal[i] = real[2 * i];
        complexImag[i] = real[2 * i + 1]
    }

    complexFFT(complexReal, complexImag);

    const resultReal = new Array(n);
    const resultImag = new Array(n);

    for (let i = 0; i < halfN; i++) {
        const angle = -2 * Math.PI * i / n;
        const cosAngle = Math.cos(angle);
        const sinAngle = Math.sin(angle);

        resultReal[i] = complexReal[i];
        resultImag[i] = complexImag[i];
        resultReal[n - i - 1] = complexReal[i] * cosAngle + complexImag[i] * sinAngle;
        resultImag[n - i - 1] = -complexReal[i] * sinAngle + complexImag[i] * cosAngle;
    }

    return [resultReal, resultImag];
}
```

Comment: If you are doing it as a programming exercise try to get a basic complex to complex radix-2 FFT working first. Then there are (at least) two choices - two real to complex conjugate symmetric done in one complex vector and unpicked at the end or one real to complex conjugate symmetric done either in place (trickier when you go to higher dimensions but more efficient) or with one extra component in complex form to hold the alternating component. (Packed form stuffs it in Im{DC} which is zero). Otherwise you are better off using an existing tested FFT package which will be much faster.

Comment: @MartinBrown I already have a basic complex to complex radix-2 FFT working, otherwise my call to `complexFFT` would be difficult. There are plenty of simple examples of that to follow. But I can find no simple examples of real to complex by way of C2C.

Comment: real to complex conjugate symmetric is widely used now and these days highly optimised libraries are available to do it. If you want to roll your own then Numerical Recipes has sample code (with a Fortran bias so [1..N] arrays). This is the C version I found online [FFT Real - CC Symmetric](https://www.foo.be/docs-free/Numerical_Recipe_In_C/c12-3.pdf). Beware that although it is in C you will need to carefully subtract 1 from the various indices in that sample code. It does one of each sort two real input vectors to two complex outputs and single real vector to half length complex.